# How can i make sure an Excel iframe updates with a static link?

Tags: html, excel, github, iframe

I have an Excel embedded iframe that has a static source URL, but even after i change the source's content my iframe does not update.

I think its cached on their servers and i dont know how to fix that.

I could not find any parameters that fix this or what other people have done.

```html
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://github.com/HWBB/ExcelLink/blob/master/schedule.xlsx?raw=true" frameborder="0" style="height:60vh; width: 100vw;"></iframe>
```

My source URL is `https://github.com/HWBB/ExcelLink/blob/master/schedule.xlsx?raw=true`.

Comment: iframe will static page so I think you should refresh this page to see update.

Comment: Refreshing doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You refresh the tab that the excel sheet is open in as well as the webpage where the iframe is embedded.

Refreshing the excel sheet is necessary. Also make sure to save the sheet prior to refreshing.